# Is it bad to read or write to NSUserDefaults in a tight loop?

Tags: ios, object, loops, nsuserdefaults

Are there any performance or other consequences for setting an object for key in the NSUserDefaults repeatedly?

```
[self.myDefaults setObject:someObject forKey:someKey];
```

and/or

```
anObject = [self.myDefaults objectForKey:someKey];
```

My loop will repeat approx 100 times within a second, and only last for a few seconds at a time.

I'll only be calling `synchronize` after the loop is finished.

Comment: What are you doing that you'd need to write to it that much?

Comment: The 'loop' is just an example to represent how often I'm reading/writing.  What I'm actually doing is responding to touch events for a pan gesture.  I'm considering reading and writing straight to NSUserDefaults to save the extra code of using extra variables and setting these to the defaults at specific places.

Comment: What are you saving to the NSUserDefaults though that also needs to respond to the UIPanGestureRecognizer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [NSUserDefaults docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) state:
"NSUserDefaults caches the information to avoid having to open the user’s defaults database each time you need a default value."

Therefore it's no different to setting or getting an object from an in-memory dictionary variable.

However, calling `[self.myDefault synchronize];` within a type loop would have a performance consequence, as this opens and writes to the defaults database on disk.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, NSUserDefaults isn't the best data store for mass amounts of data. It's recommended to write to plists, or sqlite for larger data sets. User defaults was just for a few user preference settings and isn't built for "storing data" like a typical database is.

You shouldn't really run into performance issues in the loop, though, unless if you're synchronizing for each iteration.